# Remove class isn't working with id #.parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to remove a class of an element that contains an  with an href. I have the href retrieved, however how come I can't remove the class this way?

script:

```
...

 $('#panel1').parent('li').removeClass('active'); //doesn't work....

 ...
```

html:

```
 ...
 <ul class = "tab-links">
    <!-- Each tab is Anchored to its Contents -->
    <li class = "active"><a href ="#panel1">Panel 1</a></li>
    <li><a href ="#panel2">Panel 2</a></li>
    <li><a href ="#panel3">Panel 3</a></li>
    <li><a href ="#panel4">Panel 4</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Apart from the missing quotes, there is no element with ID of `panel1` in your html.

Comment: Also, you don't need the hash as part of an ID (which is what we think you were intending), the hash comes from the css selector for an ID.

Answer (score 3):

You need quotes around the argument to `$()`. Also, `#xxx` selectors are used to search for an ID, but your anchors don't have IDs, they just have `href`. You need to do:

```
$("a[href='#panel1']").parent('li').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: What are other syntax's for searching for an <element> with a attribute of a certain value?

Comment: `$("#id")`, `$(".class")`, and `$("[attribute=value]")`. See the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around you id selector

```
$('#panel1').parent('li').removeClass('active'); //doesn't work....
```